# Can we use kotlin contracts to specify at least one of the lambda block will be executed in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, method-invocation, kotlin-contracts, kotlin-experimental

I have a function as follows.

```kotlin
fun handleResult(
    onSuccess:() -> Unit,
    onFailure:() -> Unit
){


}
```

Is there a way to specify kotlin compiler that one of the blocks between 2 is sure to be executed only once?

Usage::
I want a variable to be initialized by the handleResult block..

```kotlin
val isSuccess : Boolean
handleResult(
   onSuccess = {
      isSuccess= true
   },
   onFailure = {
      isSuccess = false
   }
)
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but someone else might be able to confirm.